# ANLTR precedence across multiple parser rules

Tags: parsing, antlr4, operator-precedence

Consider the following grammar

```
grammar precedence;

s: expr EOF;
expr: '!' expr | expr '.' ID | ID;

ID: [a-zA-Z];
WS: [ \n] -> skip;
```

Given the precedence rules of this grammar, the expression `!a.b` should produce the following parse tree

[image: Parse tree with (!a) being accessed]

In an attempt to organize my grammar, I changed it to

```
grammar precedence;

s: expr EOF;
expr: not | expr '.' ID | ID;
not: '!' expr;

ID: [a-zA-Z];
WS: [ \n] -> skip;
```

When running it, we get the following parse tree

[image: Parse three where a.b has the ! applied to it]

The ANLTR reference states

> ANTLR  resolves  ambiguities  in  favor  of  the  alternative  given  first, implicitly allowing us to specify operator precedence.

However, the position of the `not` alternative has not changed, yet is given a different precedence. Why? Is there a different rule when there's a layer of indirection like this?

Comment: I just hit the same issue. Did you discover any new insights since you asked the question?

Comment: It has been a long while since I looked at this, but I believe it was just a limitation of how antlr resolved recursion. I would love a more concrete answer, though.